# Facebook Instagram Graph Api Get Tags with username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I tried the Instagram-Graph-Api because the current Instagram-API will be shut down soon.

I want to retrieve posts, created with a specific Hashtag and read the Username who created that post.

Unfortunately the username-Field is not supported in the IG [Hashtag API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag)

> You cannot request the username field on returned media objects.

OK, that's maybe a Facebook-Limitation. So I tried to fetch the Details of an object with the [IG Media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media) API. This Api works for Media-Objects what I created with my linked Facebook-Account for the Access-Token, but it does not works with other, public accounts.

Facebook wrote:

> Fields marked with an asterisk (*) are public fields, which means they can be returned by an edge using field expansion.

And the username-Field in the documentation is wrapped with an `*`. So I think it's a public information to what we should have access to?

I do not found any limitation on facebook saying that the IG Media Api only allows to retrieve Elements from Pages where my Access-Token is authorized to, is this currently a limitation because my Facebook-App was not reviewed by Facebook?

This is the Graph-API-Call what I made:

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/18142822621010864?user_id=17841402377690736&fields=id%2Cusername&access_token=`

And this is the response what I get:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '18142822621010864' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "AMi0N96iFZ65hgvS1D1upsO"
}
}
```

Thank you
Matthias

Comment: Having the exact same issue

Comment: I also opened the issue on the facebook-community, but I'm still waiting also there for a response: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/593443381308212/?post_id=593443391308211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok did a lot of research on this one last night. And simply put, Facebook locked down their api pretty hard.

You are not able to see any specific of a media item not owned by yourself.

You are not able to see any comments when your are not tagged or mentioned in the post

You are not able to get the username of media found via hashtags for example.

You should be able to see replies on your comments added to public media you do not own.